# Need a logic to generate 25 unique nos out of 40

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, language-agnostic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To show 25 images randomly out of 40 images in a grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847843/to-show-25-images-randomly-out-of-40-images-in-a-grid-view)

Hi,

I need to create an array of 25 element every time app launches and each element is unique and lies between 0-40.

Using Random method to create a random no. from 0-40 but in this I am getting duplicate nos.

Please help me

Many Thanks
iPhone Developer11